# Function 'move' in Protractor 6.0.0 does not work

Tags: javascript, protractor

In Protractor 5.4.2 I was using mouseMove function to simulate hovering over an element. I need this to make several other elements appear. I used:

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(element).perform();
```

but with Protractor 6.0.0 the following does not work (i.e. there is no desired result of hovering simulation):

```
await browser.actions().move(element).perform();
```

I found this conversation helpful to get a general understanding of new API calls, but none of the solutions provided there proved to work in my project: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5185

I consulted this documentation, to try to understand better how move function works in 6.0.0: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/input_exports_Actions.html

My sample test:

```
 it('Hover mouse over', async() => {
    myItem = 'span.dashboard__item'
        await browser.actions().move({origin: myItem, duration:2000}).perform();
    })
```

In my code I also tried the following options:

```
await browser.actions().move({origin: element, x:2, y:3, duration: 
    2000}).click().perform()
await browser.actions({bridge: true}).move({origin: element, x: 5, y: 5, 
    duration: 2000}).perform();
await browser.actions().move({origin: element, duration:2000}).perform();
```

but to no avail. The above give: 
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

This error is not connected with the size of the project, as it is not big.

I need a way to simulate mouse hover over an element as only then buttons on it become interactable. What is the way to do this in Protractor 6.0.0? any hints?

Comment: I haven't messed with Protractor 6 yet but looking at the documentation you linked, it looks like origin should be a WebElement. The type of `myItem` is just a string in the test you posted. So that's not going to work. This is just a hunch but I'm guessing once you get your element, you need to call `.getWebElement()` and pass that as origin. It should be something like this: `myItem = element(by.css('span.dashboardItem')).getWebElement(); await browser.actions().move({origin: myItem, x:2, y:3, duration: 
    2000}).click().perform()`

Comment: I would maybe not use Protractor 6 since the documentation is not up to date and we decided to not mark it as the 'latest' version on npm. I'm glad you are trailblazing but things might not work completely. If you run into an issue, write an issue for us on GitHub. If you are interested in the new actions API, I would look into selenium-webdriver's documentation. These have completely changed from the previous actions.

Comment: Thank you @tehbeardedone for the hint. myItem is ```$('span.dashboardItem')``` in my code I just oversimplified it in the process of making  more readable for asking this question. However, I clearly missed ```.getWebElement()``` part - thanks! @cnishina I will have look at selenium-webdriver documentation then and post this issue n GtHub.

Comment: Also we are lacking docs on this so it might be nice to get a pull request against the master branch. Also just @ me and I will review it.

Answer (score 0):

i can suggest using native js functions for interacting with the browser, like mouse move, click, drag and drop. 
This is due the problems with firefox API not supporting browser.actions, or any other kind of issues that you will find with newest ver of protractor ex. 6.0

Use https://github.com/IgorSasovets/protractor-firefox-support 
you can create wrapper and extend the functionality to reach your goals.

Comment: Thanks, @Infern0, I'll have a look. Seems to be what I need.